# Show that $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is bounded if: $a_2=\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{2^2+2},\;a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2^i+i}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having troubles with the this calculus problem.

> Show that $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is bounded if:
>   $$a_2=\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{2^2+2}$$
>   $$a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2^i+i}$$

I know from manual calculation that the sequence seems to be bounded above at $\frac{7}{10}$

I have tried to use a direct proof but I couldn't solve this question.

Then, I moved on to try and use mathematical induction but I am having trouble to prove the step at $P_{n+1}$ is bounded above by 0.7.
The mathematical proposition I proposed for this M.I. is to prove it is bounded above by $0.7$.

However, I am also having trouble for the M.I. proof at the P_(n+1) step

Please help me with this question. Any method would be appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax. 

Comment: Thanks for helping me to edit my question! A lot clearer now 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
 $$ a_{n} < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{2}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{n}} $$
which is a geometric sequence with common ratio $\frac{1}{2}$. By the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence, we get
 $$ a_{n} < \frac{1}{2} \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2^{n}}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n}}< 1 $$

Comment: Thanks Shai for your help! Great and clear explanation! 

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n +n} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} =  1$$

Thus $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i+i}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a convergent sequence. In particular, it is bounded.

More directly, you can also note that your sequence is bounded by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n+n}\leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! 